# Check last array element

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I've got a string array, and I should check `i` element and `i + 1`,  for some coincidence, except the last element, because it allready checked by previous element.

```
String[] somearr = new {"first, second"};
```

`arr[i] && arr[i+1]`, allready checked the last element, and when `arr[i] = second` I've got `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
if (arr[i].equals("first") && arr[i + 1].equals("second"){
//do something;
}
```

My question is how not to check the last element because I allready checked it in previous?

Comment: in the loop, just iterate until array.length-2

Comment: yes in the loop I did not mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `index + 1` out of bound:

```
if ((index + 1) < somearr.length && somearr[index].equals("first") && somearr[index + 1].equals("second")) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
if(i< arr.length()-1 && arr[i].equals("first") && arr[i + 1].equals("second"))
```